# Jar mismatch! action bar sherlock and facebook sdk

Tags: android, facebook

im writing an app that uses  action bar sherlock and facebook sdk.
Therefore i imported those two libraries into my project and i get and error 
saying i have two jars of android-support-v4.jar

"Found 2 versions of android-support-v4.jar in the dependency list 
 but not all the versions are identical (check is based on SHA-1 only at this time).
 All versions of the libraries must be the same at this time."

what can i do? can i put one of the jars into the other library? 
they supposed to identical, but their sizes are diff..i dont wana go and change/delete libraries in the sourcode.
any ideas?

Comment: delete the one in your project,go to libs>android-support-v4.jar, I think Action Bar sherlock already has android-support-v4.jar

Comment: ty, they both have android-support-v4.jar
i found a solution: adding one as a jar and the other as a library.
still i have two diff android-support-v4.jar's but it seems the compiler can live with it. so every library as it seems uses its own android-support-v4.jar.

Comment: put your solution below and accept it as answer.

Answer (score 9):

Jar mismatch problem is happened because there are 2 versions of `android-support-v4.jar` in the dependency list one of them is included in `Facebook SDK` library and the other in `ActionBarSherlock` library.

The fix to this problem is to delete the `android-support-v4.jar` from one of these two library and copy the other `android-support-v4.jar` instead of the deleted one, in this way you will be sure you have the same version of the jar file in both libraries and you will get ride of the build error.

Answer (score 0):

adding one as a jar and the other as a library. still i have two diff android-support-v4.jar's but it seems the compiler can live with it. so every library as it seems uses its own android-support-v4.jar.